# Can't upload upload symbol files

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Q1: My project build failed when I add an upload script.

```
JSON_FILE=${PROJECT_DIR}/Blued-i-a3bc95921663.json
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:XXXXXXXXXX:ios:XXXXXXXXXXX
defaults write com.google.SymbolUpload version -integer 1
JSON=$(cat "${JSON_FILE}")
/usr/bin/plutil -replace "app_${GOOGLE_APP_ID//:/_}" -json "${JSON}"      "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload.plist"
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym
```

failed log:

```
...
warning: dump_syms: /Users/xiejing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Blued2015-c/Users/xiejing/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUploadToken.plist: Could not modify plist, error: Failed to parse value  with type -json

kgekafhlpbizzczluukmcxwihwk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Blued2015.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Blued2015: in compilation unit '/Users/xiejing/workspace/Blued2015/Blued-International-iOS/Blued/Blued/Blued2015/ThirdPart/libs/zxing/source/oned/Code128Reader.cpp' (offset 0x58c5ec):

....

warning: dump_syms: /Users/xiejing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Blued2015-ckgekafhlpbizzczluukmcxwihwk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Blued2015.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Blued2015: in compilation unit '/Users/xiejing/workspace/Blued2015/Blued-International-iOS/Blued/Blued/Blued2015/ThirdPart/libs/zxing/source/common/BitArray.cpp' (offset 0x99deed):
warning: dump_syms:        /Users/xiejing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Blued2015-ckgekafhlpbizzczluukmcxwihwk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Blued2015.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Blued2015: in compilation unit 'Blued2015/ThirdPart/libs/zxing/source/ResultPoint.cpp' (offset 0x9a6c2e):
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Q2: Also failed when I upload manually.

```
$/Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload BF574806-B49C-3B5B-A17F-558534AF82FC
>/Users/xiejing/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUploadToken.plist: Could not modify plist, error: Failed to parse value  with type -json
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying a few things:

1. Blow away the cache file used by the upload script:

   ```
   rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*
   ```
2. Create a new service account and make sure it has the Editor
   permission.  See the (updated) instructions at
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios.  Download the
   corresponding key
3. Make sure you have the latest Firebase Crash pod (1.0.7 as of
   this writing).
4. Update your script to the following (also mentioned in the above
   docs link)

   ```
   # Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file
   GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:my:app:id

   # Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you ust downloaded
   "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym" /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json"
   ```

Hopefully this will help

Comment: This versatile solution for me is invalid, if you look carefully compiled logs, you should be able to see it seems a relationship with zxing we using as third-party libraries. Please help me again.